# What .Net orms or MicroOrms support async operations and PostgreSql

Tags: dapper

What ORM's support async operations and postgresql ?

I prefer simple MicroOrms like Dapper and OrmLite because they seems to have great performance and they are really simple, but they do not support async operations as far as I can tell.

Maybe I am wrong, but isn't important to make all IO bound operations async to get the full benefits of say an async web service that needs to scale?

So what are the options regarding an MicroOrm with support for both async operations and Postgresql? I have just read about a new Orm called Insight.Data, but I am unsure whether it properly supports PostgreSql.

Comment: I have removed the Simple.Data tag as it does not support async\await at the moment.

Comment: The only RDBMS which natively supports asynchroneous executions (not fake ones like wrapping a call with a Task.Run()) on its reader is SQL Server AFAIK. You can see this by decompiling the ADO.NET data providers. The default implementation of ExecuteReaderAsync calls internally the synchroneous one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.5, I wrote a [fork of Dapper](https://github.com/bkaid/dapper-dot-net) that adds async methods that internally call [ExecuteReaderAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executereaderasync.aspx).  It is also [available on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper-Async).  I haven't tested it with Postgresql but if Dapper works with it then my fork should as well.

Comment: Dapper now has async methods in the core library (and has done for quite some time, but after your answer was posted)

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled upon this new ORM called [Insight.Database](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database) and they claim to support async queries:

```
List<Beer> beerMenu = await Database1.AsyncQuery<Beer>("FindBeer", new { Name = "Sly Fox" });
```

I did not try it yet...

Answer (score 2):

Telerik's free [OpenAccess ORM](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx) supports PostgeSQL, but I can't see anything mentioned about async. Maybe you could contact them, their online support is pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

Insight.Database has full async support and works with any .NET SqlProvider. I haven't specifically tested it on postgres, but if you post an issue on the github site, I'd gladly incorporate postgres into the test suite.

https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database

EDIT: Insight v3.0 and later supports most databases.

Answer (score 2):

[AsyncPoco](https://github.com/tmenier/AsyncPoco), a fork of [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco), supports asynchronous operations (exclusively) and  PostgeSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Dapper has had async support for some time, but only when targeting .NET 4.5. I could *probably* back-port to 4.0 using the BCL async targeting pack, but to date: I have not done so.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK the only RDBMS which natively supports asynchronous executions, provider side and server side (not fake ones like wrapping a call with a Task.Run()) on its reader, is SQL Server. You can see this by decompiling the specific ADO.NET data provider. The default implementation of ExecuteReaderAsync calls internally the synchronous one, if not overridden. Please double check by decompiling the specific ADO.NET provider because you may end up in doing database operations in the UI thread when using async and await.