# How do I use Dapper in an asynchronous controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my first time using async/await with the Dapper ORM. I keep getting the message that my controller lacks the await method. How can I correctly insert the await method in my code?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> index(int? page)
{

    if (page == null)
    {
        page = 1;
        ViewBag.page = page;
    }
    else
    {

        ViewBag.page = page;
    }
    string Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycontext"].ConnectionString;
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
    {

        sqlConnection.Open();
        var sqlM = @"SELECT * from threads order by activities desc";
        var resultM = sqlConnection.Query<thread>(sqlM).ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(resultM);
        return View(new homepage { panel = resultM });
    }


}
```

I have tried  `await Task.WhenAll(resultM);` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the warning because you aren't using any asynchronous methods in the controller. As it is, there's no reason to mark it as `async`.

In order to actually make the method asynchronous, you need to use Dapper's async methods and await them.  See [Using Async Await keywords with Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833426/using-async-await-keywords-with-dapper) for another example of this.

In your code, it would look like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> index(int? page)
{

    if (page == null)
    {
        page = 1;
        ViewBag.page = page;
    }
    else
    {

        ViewBag.page = page;
    }

    string Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycontext"].ConnectionString;
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
    {
        await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

        var sqlM = @"SELECT * from threads order by activities desc";
        var resultM = await sqlConnection.QueryAsync<thread>(sqlM);

        return View(new homepage { panel = resultM });
    }
}
```

If `resultM` must be a `List<thread>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`, you can call `ToList` - but make sure it's **after** awaiting the asynchronous call.

Comment: @user1591668 No problem! Let me know if it works for you.